# jquery-ui connected lists append output to textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I don't really know what I am doing when it comes to jQuery, and I pieced this script together. What I am trying to do is have three jquery-ui lists to be connected, which works, then capture the content of each list individually. I only actually need #sortableEquipmentDay and #sortableEquipmentNight. However if you look at the jsFiddle I included you'll see that moving items into the lists gives some random output and not the id's of the two lists as I'm looking for.

Also .append doesn't appear to clear old data but just adds onto the text inside the text area.

Any help would be awesome!

```
javaScript:
    $(function() {
        var lists = $( "#EquipmentPool, #sortableEquipmentDay, #sortableEquipmentNight" ).sortable({
            connectWith: 'ul.droptrue',

    update: function() {
            lists.each(function(){

        var DayShift = $("#sortableEquipmentDay").sortable("toArray");
        var Nightshift = $("#sortableEquipmentNight").sortable("toArray");

            $("#out1").append( DayShift.join(','));
            $("#out2").append( Nightshift.join(','));        

            });

        }

    }).disableSelection();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EsnLs/84/

Comment: Change `append` to `val` http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EsnLs/85/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use :

```
$("#out1").val( DayShift.join(','));
$("#out2").val( Nightshift.join(','));
```